# select_related django. Why i can't using select_related in my project?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i'm new in django. And i am trying to use django ORM instead of raw sql.

This is my models:

```
class DosenPublikasi(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(db_column='UserID', max_length=50, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    publikasiid = models.ForeignKey('self', db_column='PublikasiID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dosen_publikasi'

class Publikasi(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    judul = models.CharField(db_column='Judul', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nama_jurnal = models.CharField(db_column='Nama_Jurnal', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tahun_pelaksanaan = models.CharField(db_column='Tahun_Pelaksanaan', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    issn = models.CharField(db_column='ISSN', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    volume = models.CharField(db_column='Volume', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nomor = models.CharField(db_column='Nomor', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    halaman = models.CharField(db_column='Halaman', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nama_dosen = models.CharField(db_column='Nama_Dosen', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'publikasi'
```

And consider of my models. I try to create a view like this:

```
def lihat_riwayat_publikasi(request):
                username_session = request.session['username']
                hak_akses_session = request.session['hak_akses']
                publikasi = DosenPublikasi.objects.select_related().get(userid=username_session)
                data = {
                        'object_list':publikasi,
                        'username':username_session,
                        'hak_akses':hak_akses_session,
                }
                return render(request, 'lihat_riwayat_publikasi.html', data)
```

And then i send my data views to my html template:

```
 {% for publikasi in object_list %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td> <!-- forloop.counter digunakan untuk membuat angka iterasi secara otomatis(nomor) -->
              <td>{{ publikasi.tahun_pelaksanaan }}</td>
              <td>{{ publikasi.nama_dosen }} </td>
              <td>{{ publikasi.judul }} . {{ publikasi.nama_jurnal }} . ISSN: {{ publikasi.issn }} . Vol. {{ publikasi.volume }} . No. {{ publikasi.nomor }} . Hal. {{ publikasi.halaman }}</td>
              <td>
                <a href="{% url "ubah_riwayat_publikasi" publikasi.id %}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </button></a>
                <a href="{% url "delete_riwayat_publikasi" publikasi.id %}"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i> </button></a>
              </td>
            </tr> 
            {% endfor %}
```

My question:

1. Why in the result there is no data that is displayed? am i wrong in query?
2. if i'm wrong. Please tell me what is the right query that can display the data?

Because i feel i'm wrong in my views here

```
 publikasi = DosenPublikasi.objects.select_related().get(userid=username_session)
```

Thank you very much. Your input would be helpful

Comment: You probably need to specify the related fields you need to select.

Comment: do you mean like this ? 
`publikasi = DosenPublikasi.objects.select_related('publikasi').get(userid=username_session)`

that's still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DosenPublikasi.objects.get()` returns a single `DosenPublikasi`. Calling [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) will follow foreign keys from `DosenPublikasi` to reduce the number of SQL queries, but it will still return a single `DosenPublikasi`.

If there can be multiple `DosenPublikasi` for each user, then use `filter()` instead of `get()`

```
publikasi = DosenPublikasi.objects.select_related().filter(userid=username_session)
```

Then, in your template, when you loop through `object_list`, you will be looping through `DosenPublikasi`, not `Publikasi`. You need to follow the foreign key to access the `Publikasi` fields. For example:

```
{% for dosen_publikasi in object_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ dosen_publikasi.publikasiid.nama_dosen }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've tried your answer in my code. But, it still not display anything. And i try to display `Publikasi` models and it works. 
This is the code that i use in views
`publikasi = Publikasi.objects.select_related().all()`
and here is my html template
`{% for publikasi in object_list %}
              <td>{{ publikasi.nama_dosen }} </td>
            {% endfor %}  `
when i try to display `Publikasi` it works. but not for `DosenPublikasi`

Comment: I've fixed a small typo in my answer. Hopefully it will work now.